# Is it better to pass instance of whole class or just specific values?

Tags: java, actionscript-3

I am wondering if it's better to pass an instance of a whole class to another class or just specific properties of that class.  For example if I want the height property of class A in class B do I pass just the height value into class B or the whole instance of the class and use classA.height in class B?

I am torn between having the flexibility and passing the whole class or encapsulation and passing specific properties.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Could you add example source code for both approaches you are referring to?

Comment: IN your example I would bind the height values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What are you *logically* passing? Are you logically passing information about the whole person, and it so happens that at the moment you're only interested in the height? Or is the operation in B *naturally* and *clearly* only interested in the height?

Go for whatever is most logical, even if it means there's more information available than you're currently using.

Answer (score 1):

The advantages of passing a class (or {}, ie plain old object) instead of passing separate values are:

- only one argument is passed (saves on register/stack space),
- if the method that takes the class as an arg needs to read other properties sometime in the future, you don't have to change method signatures or refactor calling code, just the end points (ie the class or the guts of some other method that uses the class).

I find the second reason to be the strongest as you start to implement more event dispatching or message passing.  At the point of event creation A, gather data and stuff data in event A,  dispatch event A, B has an event listener for event A, picks up event A's data, possibly mucks with data, then needs to also dispatch N-many events C, D, and E with some of A's data, possibly appending new data.

Now say you want to pass a new 'foo' parameter from the dispatch point of event A that would be picked up by event C, D and E.  If the data you stuff into event A is a class (or even just a {}, ie base Object) then you don't need to adjust event A or event C or any other listeners.

The point I am getting at when talking about dispatching events, handling events caught is that there can be what seems like a long "distance" between where an object is created  and where it is used and passed.  The farther an object (or set of properties) travels (from method call to method call to data stuffed into a dispatched event) from its source of instantiation the more you have to pay attention to how data is passed.  By keeping it simple, ie a single class instance passed along, you just have to focus on creating object correctly and using objects correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the function of your method and how you want to use it. If in your example, all your method cares about is the height, then pass in just the height. Be as specific as possible so that the functionality of your method is clear.

Remember, just like good variable names, sensible data types also make for good documentation and readability.